# ajax call on iPhone Safari does not return

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

I am using jQuery 1.9.1, and have an issue that seems to only happen on mobile Safari intermittently.

1. on a button click, call FB.login, on mobile Safari it pops up a new page and ask user to log into FB.  Afterwards that page closes and control is returned to previous page.
2. when FB.login returns, get id and access token, and make an ajax call to our API / backend server try to login
3. login call to API returns, if response is success, redirect to home page, if response is "user does not exist", render a create account page

The problem is the call to API server.  Most of the time it is fine, however 20-30% of the time, it fails.

Fails means
 - none of ajax's done/fail/always are called
 - also tried success/error/complete, not called

I see the request on the server side, and server returns.  It could be a timeout issue but server typically returns very quickly (sub 100ms).

And again this only happens on mobile Safari.  And seems more likely on older iOS (5, 6.0, 6.1.2), vs latest 6.1.4.

I also tried jQuery 1.10.2 and 2.0.3, and ran into the same problem.

Has anyone had similar problems?

Code Sample

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: gem.conf.apiUrls.user_login_facebook,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend: gem.auth.set_request_headers
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        gem.utils.log.debug("gem.auth.login_facebook_impl: ajax done");
    }).fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        gem.utils.log.debug("gem.auth.login_facebook_impl: ajax fail");
    }).always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        gem.utils.log.debug("gem.auth.login_facebook_impl: ajax always");
    });
```

Comment: did you debug? you can easily debug using [JSBin remote](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/03/jsconsole-remote-debugging-and-jsbin.html) or any remote javascript tool, there are dozens around.

Comment: when i debug, it works great

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be a timeout issue, once I specified an explicit timeout (2.5 seconds), things worked well.  I also cleaned up the surrounding code but I don't think they are related to this ajax not returning.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the request type from 'post' to 'get' if you can. That fixed it for me. I was making a bunch of post requests in a $.when and the .done would fire intermittently on safari mobile. Probably because of the timeout issue mentioned before. I switched the request types to 'get' and everything worked fine.